# Obtaining name and value of choice list from input

Tags: python

I have a list with toppings and their prices. After the user selected the choice, I want to obtain the name of the topping and the price individually. However with `dict.get()`(in this case `answers.get('name')` for example, I don't obtain anything.

```
price=()
questions = [
    {
        'type': 'checkbox',
        'message': 'Select toppings',
        'value': price,
        'name': 'toppings',
        'choices': [
           
            {
                'name': 'Ham',
                price: 4.35
            },
            {
                'name': 'Ground Meat',
                price: 2.50               
            },
     
        ]

answers = prompt(questions, style=style)
answers.get('name')
```

Comment: You don't have a dict.get anywhere in your code. Is this a complete example?

Comment: @NickBailey yes this is a complete code, except for how to obtain the topping and price seperately (which I need for post calculations)

Comment: This might be your full code but it is not a [mre] of the issue. We don't need your full code. We just need a tiny amount of code that reproduces the issue you are asking about. The code in your question does *not* reproduce the issue and so it's entirely unhelpful.

Comment: @RandomDavis you're right, i've edited to be more concise

Comment: What do you expect the line `answers.get('name')` to do? It's not going to print anything. `get()` returns something. So, you could do something like `print(answers.get('name'))`, for example. Or `answer = answers.get('name')`. Depends on what you want to do. When you're not using a Python shell like IDLE, you can't just put a statement like that on its own line and expect something to be printed. But I don't even know if that's what you want to do. You're saying you "don't obtain anything" but that's not clear at all what that's supposed to mean. Is nothing returned, is that the problem?

Comment: @RandomDavis well the variable answers just only contains the name and not the price. That's one problem. The second one is that print(answers.get('name')) doesn't return anything

Comment: `print()` doesn't return anything, it just prints. Are you saying it doesn't print anything? I don't know what's in `answers`, because I have no idea what `prompt` is, and so I can't know why it doesn't contain what you think it does. Please show an example that is complete, self-contained, but minimal and reproducible. Including example input, expected output (and expected contents of variables), and the actual output, and actual contents of the variables.